# Importing from parent directory python

Tags: python

I have the following structure:

```
   app/
     code/
       script.py -- has a function called func
     main.py
```

How can I import `script.py` from `main.py` ?

I tried `from code.script import func` and I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.script'; 'code' is not a package`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place a `__init__.py` file in the `code` directory. This will allow your `main.py` code to import it as a module like you have tried there.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the best way is to add `__init__.py` in `code` directory  because when a regular package is imported `__init__.py` file is implicitly executed and the objects it defines are bound to names in the package’s namespace.

FYI, as an alternative you can also to this in your `main.py` before the import:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/script.py")
```